# How to insert NSTextAttachment into NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

How do I insert an `NSTextAttachment` at a specific location in an `NSAttributedString`?

Answer (score 0):

```
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
let mutableAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
mutableAttributedText.replaceCharacters(in: selectedRange, with: attributedString)
textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedText
```